# How to initially fill a WebDynpro table bound to a BAPI call result?

Tags: abap, bapi, webdynpro

I am fairly new to webdynpro abap and have the following problem:
I created a service returning a set of all existing customers. This function works well, if i test it in a litte program simply printing out the lines.

now I created a webdynpro containing a table to display these customers.
I also did the binding! AND it works, but only if an event fires the execute...function.

What I need is kind of "execute initially", means that the function gets executed when the table initially loads.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood what you did, but it sounds like you want to read about WDDOINIT at https://help.sap.com/saphelp_qim100/helpdata/en/49/ca1023d7d958c1e10000000a421937/frameset.htm

Comment: yes, i got a reply at sdn.sap.com yesterday who mentioned the WDDOINIT of the View as well.
to call the execute_<bapi> method from WDDOINIT works fine!
thank you, too.

Comment: The help.sap.com link is broken, please fix it.